# Existence of a categorical open cover for a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Recall that an open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of a topological space $X$ is categorical if every $U_i$ is contractible to a point in $X$.

Does a topological space have a categorical open cover, in general?

If the answer is no, under what conditions the answer to the above question is yes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even for locally path-connected spaces, the answer is certainly "No", because a topological space with a categorical open cover is semi-locally simply connected.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Whoops, I'm misreading your comment and then accusing you of misreading :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer.

To give a compact, connected and locally connected example, consider the subspace of $\mathbb R^2$:

$$X=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{(x,y)\,\Bigg\vert\, \left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+y^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\right\}$$

That is, the union of circles with centers $(1/n,0)$ that intersect $(0,0)$.

(This can bee seen as the one-point compactification of the space $(0,1)\times\mathbb N$.)

Then no neighborhood of $(0,0)$ is contractible, so it has no categorical open cover.

This space is called the [Hawaiian Earring.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring)

Sufficient conditions are hard, other than the obvious - that every $x\in X$ must have a neighborhood that is contractible to a point in $X$ (which is also necessary.)

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't remember the name. Thanks for reminding me, @Dap

Comment: Let $X$ be a para compact and path connected. Is that true for this space?

Comment: @Mojtaba: the Hawaiian Earring is paracompact (it's a closed subspace of $\mathbb R^2$) and path connected